# How to bring an image inside SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

I've come up with this SVG image.

```
<svg width="250px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 250 250" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

   <def>
   </def>
        <g id="i-define-a-black-ring-yellow" fill="#img10"  transform="translate(20.000000, 20.000000)">
            <g id="Group">
                <circle id="Oval" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="2" cx="100" cy="100" r="100">

                </circle>
                <circle id="Oval" fill="#228B22" fill-rule="nonzero" cx="171" cy="31" r="16">

                </circle>
                <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100" begin="0s" dur="10s" repeatDur="indefinite"/>
            </g>
        </g>
</svg>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9zkfodwp/1377/

Now, I wanted an image inside the circle. So, I tried to use a `clip-path1` and the code is below: But, that image doesn't appear here.

```
<svg width="250px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 250 250" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

   <def>
            <clipPath id="myCircle">
               <circle id="Oval" fill="#228B22" fill-rule="nonzero" cx="171" cy="31" r="16">
               </circle>
            </clipPath>
   </def>
    <g id="i-define-a-black-ring-yellow" fill="#img10"  transform="translate(20.000000, 20.000000)">
        <g id="Group">
            <circle id="Oval" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="2" cx="100" cy="100" r="100">

            </circle>
             <image width="50" height="35" xlink:href="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/videotutorials/images/coding_ground_home.jpg" clip-path="url(#myCircle)" />
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100" begin="0s" dur="10s" repeatDur="indefinite"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9zkfodwp/1380/

My questions are:

1. Chrome doesn't display the image as in the above fiddle though.

[image]

2. The one in the fiddle - doesn't actually fit in to a circle. The image is in a square shape.

[image]

(The book image is in rectangle shape - shouldn't be it inside the circle ? As we are filling the circle with the image ?

Any ideas on what should be done on this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: I have Chrome on Mac, and it does show the image on the second fiddle.

Comment: I'm on Chrome for PC (67.0.3396.79) and it's working fine for me as well. Also, what do you mean with the second part? Can you give an example of what you need it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your fiddle:

1. It is `<defs>`, not `<def>`. That whole section was being ignored.
2. Your image and the clip path circle were in different places. They didn't overlap with one another.  I've updated the `<image>` to be centred over the clip path circle.

```html
<svg width="250px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 250 250" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myCircle">
      <circle id="Oval" cx="171" cy="31" r="16"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <g id="i-define-a-black-ring-yellow" fill="#img10"  transform="translate(20.000000, 20.000000)">
    <g id="Group">
      <circle id="Oval" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="2" cx="100" cy="100" r="100"/>
      <image x="146" y="14" width="50" height="35"
             xlink:href="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/videotutorials/images/coding_ground_home.jpg"
             clip-path="url(#myCircle)" />
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100" begin="0s" dur="10s" repeatDur="indefinite"/>
    </g>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking at. Thanks for the detailed info. thanks.

Comment: However, when I copy the above <svg> code  & created a `fortesting.svg` file. Created a .html page where I reference this file. But, my chrome shows `no-image` sign. Should something else needs to be done here ? 
`<html>

<div>
 <img src='C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\folder\fortesting.svg'/>
</div>
</html>`

Comment: Also, how did u arrive at the `x,y` for the image ? Is it via `trail and error` method or are there any tools to achieve the same ? Thanks.

Comment: Look at your browser dev console (Net/Network tab) to find out why it is failing. If you are using Chrome and `file://` scheme, try using FF instead.

Comment: For the image position, I just took the circle position and subtracted half the image width and height: `171-50/2=146`, `31-35/2~=14`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're tying to do.

you need to flip the image on the x-y axis, you can do that by adding scale it and add transformation.

check this code:

```html
<svg width="350px" height="350px" viewBox="0 0 350 350" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

   <def>
            <clipPath id="myCircle">
               <circle id="Oval" fill="#228B22" fill-rule="nonzero" cx="171" cy="31" r="16">
               </circle>
            </clipPath>
   </def>
    <g id="i-define-a-black-ring-yellow" fill="#img10"  transform="translate(20.000000, 20.000000)">
        <g id="Group" >
            <circle id="Oval" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="2" cx="100" cy="100" r="100">

            </circle>
             <image width="50" height="35" xlink:href="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/videotutorials/images/coding_ground_home.jpg" clip-path="url(#myCircle)" transform="scale (-1, 1) translate(-60, 45)" />
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100" begin="0s" dur="10s" repeatDur="indefinite"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```